# How to inline css in controller action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, mailchimp, premailer

I have to generate a html code for [mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) template. The idea is to have an action in [active_admin](http://activeadmin.info/) rails gem to generate html source code and mailchimp editable region. The html to be generated need to have all css style inlined. I already use [roadie-rails](https://github.com/Mange/roadie-rails) for other transactional emails. I know that roadie can make the css inlined with mailer but I have not seen any example to generate inline-css  from  a normal rails controller action or from a string. below is my  example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Question do
 batch_action :mailchimp do |selection|
   @questions = Question.find(selection)
   html_text = render_to_string :mailchimp, layout: 'newsletter'

   # need to parse html_text to have css inlined
   # ...
   # ...

   render text: html_text, content_type: Mime::TEXT
 end
end
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.